# Xtext reference by position, no single point of declaration

Tags: grammar, dsl, xtext

I want to create a dsl to define an attributed grammar. Here is an example grammar specification written in my dsl:

```
RootSymbol -> AdditiveValue {
  impl = {
    1.calc
    "out " 1.result;
  }
}
AdditiveValue -> AdditiveValue "+" Number {
  result = #0
  calc = {
    1.calc
    3.calc
    "add " 0.result " " 1.result " " 3.result;
  }
}
AdditiveValue -> AdditiveValue "-" Number {
  result = #0
  calc = {
    1.calc
    3.calc
    "sub " 0.result " " 1.result " " 3.result;
  }
}
AdditiveValue -> Number {
  result = 1.result
  calc = 1.calc
}
Number -> "0|[1-9][0-9]*" {
  result = #0
  calc = {
    "set " 0.result " " 1.value;
  }
}
```

Input:

```
100 + 42 - 63 + 55
```

Output:

```
set 0 100
set 1 42
add 2 0 1
set 3 63
sub 4 2 3
set 5 55
add 6 4 5
out 6
```

Explanation:

The grammar consists of three non terminal symbols:

- `RootSymbol` has one rule
- `AdditiveValue` has three rules which allow to derive productions like the input above
- `Number` has one rule which maps to the regex that matches a single number

Also, the grammar specification defines how the input can he translated to the output, so the `Number` just outputs a *set* command, the `AdditiveValue` outputs the output of both operators and then an *add* or *sub* command and the `RootSymbol` outputs the output of its `AdditiveValue` and then the *out* command.

Now, I want to define an Xtext grammar for this dsl and have the following two questions:

**Question 1**

How can I split the declaration of an identifier? In the example above, I have three rules for the symbol `AdditiveValue`. I know that if I have one place where I declare a symbol, I can easily implement that in Xtext. However, in my dsl I have multiple places to declare one symbol because I need to be able to declare multiple rules per symbol.

**Question 2**

How can I reference a symbol by its position? In the example above (second rule), the expression 1.calc should reference the calc attribute of the first part of the production of the surrounding rule. To be clear, it should reference the calc attribute of the `AdditiveValue` symbol.

Any help is appreciated!

---

**Update**

Be sure to understand the difference between the grammar specification in Xtext and the grammar specification using my dsl. They are two different things: I want to define a grammar in Xtext that matches a grammar specification that is written in my dsl. I want to do this just to have an editor for my dsl, not to use Xtext as code generator. The grammar that is written in my dsl is used by an external compiler program to translate an input to an output. Also, the example grammar above, that is written in my dsl is just that: A simple example for my dsl. The grammar could be much more complex to match any [Context-free language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language).

Comment: this looks really wired to me. in xtext the abstract synatx tree and operations on the abstract syntax tree (code generation or interpretation) and two different things. so what you have i a simple expression grammar and a interpreter that outputs this information and calculates the stuff?!?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I clarified this in the question.

Comment: so if output is created by the compiler this question is only about expressions? do you know http://blog.efftinge.de/2010/08/parsing-expressions-with-xtext.html

Comment: No, I want to have an editor for my dsl. my dsl is used to define a grammar for an external compiler. I added the sections Input and Output only to give you a chance to understand my dsl better. Xtext never sees the Input and does not generate the Output. It only works with the first code section which is the grammar specifiction, written in my dsl. This question is not about expression parsing. Only the example that I used to present my question is about expression parsing.

Comment: so you want to write an editor for grammars? you cannot have multiple things go into one. but that is only convention. so you could simply reference to any/the first found in scope. for referencing by position this is simply a matter of "naming" of elements in the scope.

Comment: You are right, I want to create an editor for grammars. (1) If there are multiple declarations of the same thing in the same scope, is there a way to check whether they all contain the same declarations in their subscopes? Compare to the attributes result and calc of the nonterminal `AdditiveValue`. How can I ensure, all rules for the same symbol define the same set of attributes? (2) How can I change the naming of elements? I know about the IQualifiedNameProviders interface, but was not able to figure out how to use it.

Comment: for the qualifiednameprovider you may look at https://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2011/07/16/iqualifiednameproviders-in-xtext-2-0/ for the consistency: implement a (or a bunch of) check(s) in the Validator